# How can I get the limits of the 95% CI for the intercepts of all regression-lines in the R package segmented?

Tags: r

I am working with the R-package "segmented" at the moment.

I have simple data where y depends on x via a linear relationship with one breakpoint. X ranges from 20 to 100 and y from 8 to 16. The breakpoint is at 62.

I can get (or estimate from the standard error) the confidence intervals for the slope and the intercept for the first regression line (the one, that is closer to 0 in the coordinate system, left of the breakpoint).

But I can only get the slope with its confidence interval and the intercept itself out of R for the second regression line (the one, that is to the right of my breakpoint and thus further away from 0), not the limits of the CI of the intercept.

How can I get the intercepts + upper and lower limits of the confidence intervals for BOTH regression lines?

```
    out.lm<-lm(b~a)
    library(segmented)
    segreg<-segmented(out.lm, seg.Z=~a)
    slope(segreg)
    confint(segreg)
    intercept(segreg)
    print.segmented(segreg)
    predict(segreg)
    summary(segreg)
```

This is how b looks like, a follows below:

```
 [1] 14.100000 15.300000 16.833333 10.333333 12.533333 12.866667 14.433333 16.000000
  [9] 14.533333 12.233333 15.533333 11.633333 15.733333 12.766667 14.200000 15.200000
 [17] 13.300000 15.500000 12.700000 13.800000 13.866667 13.866667 13.600000 15.566667
 [25] 15.533333 13.900000 14.200000 14.733333 13.800000 14.233333 13.833333  7.733333
 [33] 12.633333 12.833333 13.700000 13.266667 11.900000 14.400000 10.900000 11.300000
 [41] 12.833333 14.200000 12.266667 13.100000 14.633333 12.200000 12.266667  8.166667
 [49] 11.466667  9.833333 13.133333 13.766667 12.466667 12.633333 12.333333 12.333333
 [57] 13.066667 11.033333 11.500000 12.133333 14.166667 12.333333 10.966667 11.433333
 [65] 13.333333 12.033333  9.866667 11.966667  9.800000 10.300000 10.766667  7.833333
 [73] 13.766667 11.433333  8.466667  9.933333  6.466667 10.233333  7.300000 10.533333
 [81] 10.433333  9.400000 10.300000  9.133333  9.633333  9.600000  8.466667  7.733333
 [89]  9.233333  8.600000 11.400000  7.233333  8.800000  7.700000  8.533333 10.000000
 [97]  6.933333 10.200000  4.700000  9.100000 10.033333  8.066667  9.266667 10.666667
[105]  9.700000  9.333333  7.900000  9.166667
> print(a)
  [1] 33 33 32 31 31 30 30 30 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 28 28 28 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
 [30] 27 27 27 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 [59] 24 24 23 23 23 23 23 23 22 22 22 22 22 22 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 20 20 20
 [88] 20 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 17 17 16 16 16 16
```

Sorry, if I am doing everything wrong here. I have never posted anything about programming at all anywhere and this is really not my business. I understand basic R, but thats it. However, I could not find an answer to my question anywhere in the internet, although it seems to be very simple to me. However, I can not find the values anywhere. This is very frustrating:-/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I tried to improve. Sorry, if my question is still not of the needed quality. I am really not an expert in this field and not experienced. But it would be really important for me to get an answer :-/. Somewhere the confidence intervals for BOTH regression lines must be hidden... Thank yout!